# variable not recognized PHP POO

Tags: php, class, variables, undefined

I've a file data.php with different classes. 
And in other file I make the require call.

```
<?php

include_once('data.php');
$db= new dataManager(); // here 
class Manager{

//$db= new dataManager(); here doesn't work an error occurs


function savingData($ob )//obj 
{
      $db.saveData($ob);//error undefined variable $db
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `->` to call function with objects in php

```
$db->saveData($ob);
```

Also you need to pass `$ob` to **manager class function**

```
$newobj= new Manager();
$newobj->savingData($ob);
```

Answer (score -1):

Okey after search I remembered global word

only we need to add

global $variable; in every function.

works yet.

```
<?php

include_once('data.php');
$db= new dataManager(); // here 
class Manager{

function savingData($ob )//obj 
{
  global $db; //<---
  $db.saveData($ob);//error solved
}
```

Comment: you'll just have another problem very soon, believe me.